# How to stream with ffmpeg via http protocol

Tags: http, ffmpeg, flowplayer

I'm currently doing a stream that is supposed to display correctly within Flowplayer. 
First I send it to another PC via RTP. Here, I also checked with VLC that the codec etc. arrive correctly, which they do.

Now I want to expose this stream to Flowplayer as a file, so it can be displayed, via something I used in VLC: 
`http://localhost:8080/test.mp4`
for example.

The full line I got is: `ffmpeg -i input -f mp4 http://localhost:8080/test.mp4`

However, no matter how I try to do this, I only get an input/output error. Is this only possible with something like ffserver or another?

What I think is this doesn't work because ffmpeg can't act as a server; on VLC it works since it can. (Though VLC ruins the codecs I set and it can't be read afterwards for some reason)

A (sort of) workaround I can use is saving the RTP stream to a file, and then letting flowplayer load it. This, however, only works once the file is not accessed anymore; I get a codec error otherwise.

Comment: check the docs : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide

Comment: I've already read through them a few times, but it did not resolve my specific issue.

Comment: Use flv instead of mp4 if you're attempting live streaming: `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 2000k -g 50 http://localhost:8080/test.flv` Also see http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites

Comment: Sadly, I'm still getting `http://localhost:8080/test.flv: Input/output error` then.

Comment: Where you able to fix it?

Comment: @Cito I don't think I was, but now I am creating m3u8 playlists over HTTP, which Flowplayer can read in using a plugin. Works very well.

Comment: What error message?

Comment: Please also provide information like an error message and what software you are using to provide the file over `https://localhost:8080/` as this requires serving the file from the system you're using ffmpeg on. The best guess I can make now is that there is nothing serving the file on the system where ffmpeg is being run from

Answer (score 10):

To have FFmpeg act as an HTTP server, you need to pass the `-listen 1` option. Additionally, `-f mp4` will result in a non-fragmented MP4, which is not suitable for streaming. You can get a fragmented MP4 with `-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov`. A full working command line is:

```
ffmpeg -i input -listen 1 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov http://localhost:8080
```

Other options you may find helpful are `-re` to limit the streaming speed to the input framerate, `-stream_loop -1` to loop the input, and `-c copy` to avoid reencoding.

Comment: When I do this ffmpeg shows a bunch of lines and then 'handler_name  : VideoHandler' and then sits there idling. I can't seem to play the stream from another computer. When I try to play this with vlc I get in the logs: 'no access_demux modules matched'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -4):

you need this command line

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -s 320x240 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

make sure that your feed name ends with ".ffm" and if it's not the case, then add "-f ffm" before your feed URL, to manually specify the output format (because ffmpeg won't be able to figure it out automatically any more), like this "-f ffm http://localhost:8090/blah.bleh".

Comment: getting error at the input video file 'inappropriate ioctl for device'